# Python Interpreter Invalid when i configurePycharm

Tags: odoo

When I configure odoo with pycharm, I face the following issue:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My personal experience - python 3.8 doesn't fully compatible with Odoo. So I changed it with lower version and works great.

You can try with python 3.7 or 3.6 version.